# Switching from self-managed certificate to google-managed certificate issue: "Specified IP address is in-use and would result in a conflict."

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

So I currently have a self-managed certificate, but I want to switch to a google-managed certificate. The google docs for it say to keep the old certificate active while the new one is provisioned. When I try to create a google-managed certificate for the same ingress IP, I get the following error: `Invalid value for field 'resource.IPAddress': 'xx.xxx.xx.xx'. Specified IP address is in-use and would result in a conflict.`

How can I keep the old certificate active, like it tells me to, if it won't let me start provisioning a certificate for the same ingress?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if 2 load balancers are sharing the same IP address ([source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-multicluster-ingress/blob/master/troubleshooting.md)). most likely you would have to detach that IP - or add another IP and then swap, once the certificate had been provisioned. it's difficult to tell by the error message, while not knowing which command had been issued.